# Jmeter Query new user

Tags: jmeter

First of all apologies for the below question.

Am from a Testing background for the past 8 years and very novice to Jmeter.
I went through the Jmeter site, and ran a sample recording using the jmeter.apache.org site and it went fine.

I want to test my knowledge and understanding.
So, I did the following way.

1. Created a thread group.
2. Added a config element HTTP Default Requests with server name as mail.google.com.
3. Added a Sampler as HTTP request, set the METHOD to POST and gave the username and password, and i ran the test.

When i see the Results Viewer, i could see the login page of gmail, I need to know how to pass my username and password and simulate the clicking of Submit button and getting the next page.

Please help, am very new and will really appreciate if it's explained as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use jmeter proxy :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

Then modify and variabilize what need to be

Answer (score 0):

You can give the username and password and submit as request parameters in the HTTP post request. See the screenshot below:

[image: example request]